# How to add data to JSON via Datatables and Node.js?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a table that I made via Datatables that is feeded by a JSON file, but I have no clue as to how add data to it. Using Node.js as back-end.

This is my code:

```
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th>Confirmado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            "ajax" : {"url":"/personas.json", "dataSrc":"personas"},
            "columns" : [
                {"data" : "id"},
                {"data" : "nombre"},
                {"data" : "apellido"},
                {"data" : "email"},
                {"data" : "confirmado"}
            ]
        });
    });

    $("#btnAdd").click(add);

    function add(){

    }
</script>
```

The objective is to have 'btnAdd' pop up a window with a form where I can fill in data, and then add it to the JSON file, and show it on the table, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write with JavaScript from client side. You can with node on the server. But at client side, not. The most you can do is try to manipulate this JSON file with some other language like PHP, Ruby or Python among others. That, or use a real database... in which case, you will also need some of the previously mentioned languages.

Answer (score 0):

According to Document:

> New rows can be added to a DataTable using the row.add() API method.
>   Simply call the API function with the data for the new row (be it an
>   array or object). Multiple rows can be added using
>   the rows.add() method (note the plural). Data can likewise be updated
>   with the row().data() and row().remove() methods.
>   https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: This, however, will not save the added values on the JSON file. If you just want to emulate, the adding, this is good enough. If you want to save... not enough.

Comment: If you wan to store it, you should make an API in back-end . Send a request containing new fields by Ajax and store it usuing a back-end language

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using Node.js with this, probably should have mentioned this.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

Comment: I can't use mongo or any database. Only the JSON file.